# Consulta SQL para obtener todos los campos en registros duplicados por dos campos simultáneos

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla [INSCRIPCIONES] que tiene varios campos (ID, NOMBRES, TELEFONO, FECHA, EDAD, DESCUENTO, etc.).
Necesito ver TODOS los campos, pero únicamente de aquellos registros que tengan duplicado NOMBRES y TELEFONO (ambos) dentro de la tabla.

Ejemplo:

```
`    ID  NOMBRE TELEFONO  EDAD 
`    01  Juan   111       15 
`    02  Luis   111       16 
`    03  Juan   111       18 
`    04  Luis   222       21 
`    05  Pedro  333       17 

`    
`    Resultado:
`    01  Juan  111       15
`    03  Juan  111       18
```

He intentado con GroupBy, pero pierdo la posibilidad de ver el ID que necesito.
El resultado esperado es todos los campos para los registros con duplicados en NOMBRES + TELEFONO...

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, para obtener los `Nombre` y `Telefono` repetidos, simplemente agrupamos por estas columnas y solo traemos aquellos grupos con más de una fila

```
SELECT NOMBRE,TELEFONO 
       FROM INSCRIPCIONES
       GROUP BY NOMBRE,TELEFONO 
       HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Y ahora, para obtener las filas completas para estos casos, solo deberemos hacer un `JOIN` con la consulta anterior:

```
SELECT *
       FROM INSCRIPCIONES I
       INNER JOIN (SELECT NOMBRE,TELEFONO 
                          FROM INSCRIPCIONES
                          GROUP BY NOMBRE,TELEFONO  
                          HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
             ) D
             ON D.NOMBRE = I.NOMBRE
             AND D.TELEFONO = I.TELEFONO
```

Comment: Genial @Patricio-Moracho ! Muchas gracias!
Funcionó excelente, y además entendí (y aprendí) el mecanismo correcto para lo que necesitaba!
Muchas gracias!!